# image not resizing on browser window resize - caused by absolute position?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ive got a site with side by side divs, one of which is absolute positioned. The absolute positioned div is the nav area and as such is set up to stay static on scroll (you can see it here: evanbeltran.com).

When you click onto an image page, though, if the browser window is too small, the image ends up UNDER the nav div. Ive tried the max width and height css, but they dont do anything no matter where i put them. What id like is to figure out how to get images in the non-absolute positioned div to resize. You can check out what i mean here: http://evanbeltran.com/portsites/vansspace.html

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Remove the width and margin-right from #content2 then add:

#content2 {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

// Remove the margin-left from .image so it looks like this:
.image {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -130px;
  padding: 10px;
}

// set a max width on your image
.padder {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[image]